# Django manage.py test

Tags: python, django, testing

When running:

`./manage.py test appname`

How can I disable all the stats/logging/output after "OK"?

- I have already commented out the entire logging section - no luck.
- Also commented out any print_stat calls - no luck
- my manage.py is pretty bare so it likely isn't that.

I run many tests and constantly have to scroll up thousands of terminal lines to view results.
Clearly, I am new to Python/Django and it's testing framework, so I would appreciate any help.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 2.133s

OK
     1933736 function calls (1929454 primitive calls) in 2.133 seconds

    Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      1    0.000    0.000    2.133    2.133 <string>:1(<module>)
     30    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:8(__new__)
      4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Cookie.py:315(_quote)
     26    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Cookie.py:333(_unquote)
     10    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Cookie.py:432(__init__)
     28    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Cookie.py:441(__setitem__)
      .
      . 
      .
      2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.gmtime}
     18    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.localtime}
     18    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.strftime}
    295    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}
    556    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {zip}
```

If it helps, I am importing:

```
from django.utils import unittest

class TestEmployeeAdd(unittest.TestCase):
        def setUp(self):
```

Comment: I don't see what is what you want to remove.

Comment: Everything below "OK". Basically I do NOT want to see any of the stats. I would only like to see if the tests passed or failed.

Comment: Are you on Linux/Unix or a similar shell?

Comment: Mac terminal using virtualenv for a Python-based environment

Comment: I don't have this happen on GNU/Linux, I don't see where you're getting that profiling info from. Make sure you aren't importing the python profiler somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `unix`-like shell (Mac does) you can use [the `head` command](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?head) to do the trick like this:

```
python manage.py test appname | head -n 3
```

Switch the number `3` for the one you need to truncate the output after the `OK` line.

Also you can test if you like more the output yielded by setting the `verbosity` of the command to minimal like this:

```
python manage.py test appname -v 0
```

Hope this helps!